# How to remove DATABASECHANGELOG from liquibase sql diff output?

Tags: liquibase

I use liquidbase to compare two databases:

```
call liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ^
  --classpath=../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar ^
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skryb" ^
  --username=skryb ^
  --password=skryb ^
  --changeLogFile=%Build%.xml ^
  updateSQL > %Build%.sql 2>e2
```

how can I avoid lines like this:

`INSERT INTO`DATABASECHANGELOG`.....`

in output SQL?

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't... These are essential operations used to track the changesets applied to your database.

You could pass the SQL thru some sort of filter, but you'd end up with SQL that does not represent the operations that liquibase would normally perform. More importantly if you applied the filtered SQL to your database, you'd cause later problems for liquibase should you attempt an automatic migration (it would think the changeset is unapplied).

I'm guessing you're trying to show the SQL to a 3rd party like a DBA? In that case show them what liquibase is doing, demonstrate how each change to the database is being recorded. Sell it as an audit feature of your application.